# How to iterate over a vector data member from an overridden operator<<

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

This is my test program. The variable s1 contains a vector that contains objects of a user-defined type. I want to overload the << operator to print this vector nicely, one element per line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myclasses.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    myclass s1;

    s1.add_point(7000, 10);
    s1.add_point(8000, 11);
    s1.add_point(9000, 12);

    cout << s1 << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Here's the class definition. Basically it's just an array of another user-defined objects. I want the << operator to print all entries, one per line. Assume that "anotherclass" has the needed support methods.

```
class myclass {
    vector<anotherclass> ps;
public:
    void add_point(double, double);
    friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &out, const myclass &s );
};

void myclass::add_point(double first, double second) {
    ps.push_back(anotherclass(first, second));
}

ostream &operator<<( ostream &out, const myclass &s ) {
    vector<anotherclass>::iterator itr;
    vector<anotherclass> psp=s.ps; // Why do I need this? Why can't I use s.ps.begin() and s.ps.end() in the for loop directly?
    for ( itr=psp.begin() ; itr != psp.end() ; ++itr ) {
        cout << "(" << itr->get_first() << "," << itr->get_second() << endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

I have commented one line that I needed to add to get this to work in my program. I have no idea why that line is needed. Could somebody explain it to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `iterator` member type always allows you to modify the referenced object. Therefore you can't get an `iterator` from a `const &` argument such as `s`. You need to declare the local variable to have type `vector< anotherclass >::const_iterator`. Every container class has a `const_iterator` in parallel with `iterator`.

The reason your one-line fix works is that the newly-constructed `vector` is not `const`, unlike the function parameter it was constructed from.

In C++11, you can just use `auto itr = s.ps.begin()` and not ever name the iterator type. Or just use `for ( auto const &obj : s.ps )` and forgo iterators completely.

Comment: Great! I have two huge books on C++ that I've been studying including Bjarne's Principle and Practices tome. Neither book mentions this. (Bjarne's book has a single mention of constant iteraters in a table in Appendix B). Thanks for the other tips too.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is because you declare s as const, so accessing to its iterator is not permitted.
When you use vector psp=s.ps, your program essentially copy s.ps to a new vector psp which is modifiable.